# How to persist JPA Map @OneToMany

Tags: java, jpa, dictionary, one-to-many

I have an entity class which contains a map. The map references ranked entities of type Child.

```
@Entity
public class Parent implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;
  @OneToMany
  @JoinTable    
  private Map<String, Child> ranking;
}

@Entity
public class Child implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;
}
```

I put objects into the map like so:

```
ranking.put(1, childA);
ranking.put(2, childB);
ranking.put(3, childA);
```

The Child class does not reference Parent. The map key is a ranking attribute I want to persist. I do not want the ranking attribute to be part of the Child class.
I want to achieve a join table (parent_child) where the columns look like:

```
|-------------| |----------| |---------------|
| parent      | | child    | | parent_child  |
|-------------| |----------| |---------------|
| id          | | id       | | parent_id     |
| ...         | | ...      | | child_id      |
|             | |          | | ranking       | <-- missing
|-------------| |----------| |---------------|
```

Actually, I do not get the rank column.
What am I missing? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted at above, you would need to create an additional Entity, say Relationship. You could then map this as Map like:

```
@Entity
public class Parent implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Integer id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy ="parent")
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
  @MapKeyColumn(name = "ranking")
  private Map<String, Relationship> ranking;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the solution. I slightly modified the names to express the semantics, for the record: `@MapKeyColumn` defines the column created for the map key in the Relationship table, in my case it's the rank. `@JoinColumn` defines a column in the Relationship table that contains the foreign key to the parent table.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use map in your case, for this problem you should create an entity for your `parent_child` and create `@NamedQuery` to return the rank with children

Comment: Sounds promising but I can't imagine the outcome. I'd like to see a solution based on this idea. Could you elaborate a little bit more on it?